# Laravel 4.2 - 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-rotas

Tenho uma rota que estava funcionando normalmente e parou de funcionar sem motivo aparente. Ela tem a seguinte configuração:

```
Route::put('/clientes', 'Clientes@update');
```

O erro que eu recebo é:

```
Method Not Allowed
The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /clientes/.
```

Se eu simplesmente modificar a url para:

> /qualquer-coisa

Funciona normalmente, alguém pode explicar esse problema, pois não faz o mínimo sentido pra mim. Quando eu executo o comando "php artisan routes" a rota está lá, mas sempre recebo esse erro. Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Obs: já tenho várias rotas funcionando nesses padrões.

Comment: Por que você usa `Route::put()` ? O `put` especificamente.

Answer (score 2):

Para acessar o método `PUT`, seria necessário que a requisição feita a essa url também fosse do tipo `PUT`. Essa requisição não pode ser feita via formulário, apenas via `ajax`. Formulários

O method not allowed está sendo retornado porque ele não é um método aceito; ou seja, você está fazendo uma requisição de outro tipo, quando a esperada é a do tipo `PUT`.

Há um problema que meu colega programador já me alertou é que, se você acessar também a `url` com uma `/` no final, a requisição é reconhecida como `GET`. Tente remover a barra do final da url requisitada.

As requisições feitas por um navegador, geralmente, é do tipo `GET`.

Isso não ficou especificado na pergunta: Se a requisição foi feita pelo navegador ou não.

Comment: É verdade sobre o `GET`. Um dia estava com problemas ao acessar uma página via Ajax. Estava entendendo como `POST`. Daí eu pensei: vou colocar `postPagina()` no Controller, então. Tanto faz. Mesmo assim não funcionou. Estava levando para outro caminho. Tipo `localhost/url`. Daí que caiu a ficha que era a `/` no final da URL no parâmetro `url` do Ajax. Mais Um.